# When I use eval with aggregate, I lose the variable names

Tags: r

I have a bit of code which aggregates data:

```
pivot.present.RT <- with(
  subset(correct.data, relevantTarget == 1),
  aggregate(
    data.frame(RT = RT),
    list(
      identifier = identifier,
      set.size = relevantSS,
      stimulus = stimulus
      ),
    mean
    )
  )
```

I would like to make this more flexible by specifying different column names to take the place of "relevantSS". I thought I could do this with eval:

```
set.size.options <- c("relevantSS","irrelevantSS")
pivot.present.RT <- with(
  subset(correct.data, relevantTarget == 1),
  aggregate(
    data.frame(RT = RT),
    list(
      identifier = identifier,
      eval(parse(text = paste("set.size = ", set.size.options[relevant.index]))),
      stimulus = stimulus
      ),
    mean
    )
  )
```

However, when I run the second bit of code, while it does correctly aggregate the data, I lose the variable name "set.size". If I call str, I get output like this:

```
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ identifier: Factor w/ 9 levels "aks","ejr","ejr3",..: 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 ...
 $ Group.2   : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 8 8 ...
 $ stimulus  : Factor w/ 2 levels "moving","stationary": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RT        : num  1161 1026 1257 1264 1324 ...
```

If I run the original code, it correctly identifies the second variable as "set.size".

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I think `get` might be more appropriate than `eval`/`parse`.

```
set.size.options <- c("relevantSS","irrelevantSS")
pivot.present.RT <- with(
  subset(correct.data, relevantTarget == 1),
  aggregate(
    data.frame(RT = RT),
    list(
      identifier = identifier,
      set.size = get(set.size.options[relevant.index]),
      stimulus = stimulus
      ),
    mean
    )
  )
```

That said, I'd probably prefer something like this:

```
d2 <- subset(correct.data, relevantTarget == 1)
doby <- subset(d2, select=c("identifier", set.size.options[relevant.index], "stimulus"))
names(doby) <- c("identifier", "set.size", "stimulus")
aggregate(d2[,"RT",drop=FALSE], doby, mean)
```

And others will undoubtedly chime in with `plyr` solutions...

Comment: +1 Yes, I should have suggested an alternative to `eval`/`parse`.

Comment: Thanks. I used eval/parse because I'm more familiar with MATLAB, which has an eval function. Get looks to be a bit simpler here.

Comment: Welcome to R! Regarding `parse` in R, `library(fortunes); fortune(106)` is usually good advice.

Comment: But the main thing is putting the list name outside of `get`/`eval`

Answer (score 1):

Put the grouping variable name outside of `eval(parse(...))`, like this:

```
set.size.options <- c("relevantSS","irrelevantSS")
pivot.present.RT <- with(
  subset(correct.data, relevantTarget == 1),
  aggregate(
    data.frame(RT = RT),
    list(
      identifier = identifier,
      set.size = eval(parse(text = set.size.options[relevant.index])),
      stimulus = stimulus
      ),
    mean
    )
  )
```